# pstree em programa c++

Tags: c++, sistema-operacional, processo

**Deverá ser mostrada a árvore de processos no ínicio da execução, no momento
em que todos os processos estão criados e no momento final do programa. (pstree -s )**

Esse requisito acima em negrito faz parte do desenvolvimento desse código abaixo, o códido está funcionando, porém não sei como exibir a árvore desse processo. Coloquei o comando *system(pstree -s pidPai)* mas não mostra a árvore desse processo, e sim a árvore de todos os processos do sistema, teste com printf, sprinf, fprintf mas nenhum funciona, alguém sabe me dizer como usar esse comando exigido para que seja exibido a árvore de cada processo do programa?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
void
proc_neto1(int dtnasc) {
int num_segundos = 0;
while (true) {
    sleep(1);
    num_segundos ++;
    cout << "Sou o processo neto 1 (PID " << getpid() << "), estou rodando   há " << num_segundos << " segundos." << endl;
}
}

void
proc_neto2(int dtnasc) {
int num_segundos = 0;
while (true) {
    sleep(1);
    num_segundos ++;
    cout << "Sou o processo neto 2 (PID " << getpid() << "), estou rodando há " << num_segundos << " segundos." << endl;
    if (dtnasc + num_segundos == 60) {
        cout << "Neto 2 ficou louco! Matou seu pai (PID " << getppid() << ")" << endl;
        kill(getppid(), SIGKILL);
    }
    if (dtnasc + num_segundos == 63) {
        cout << "Não aguentando a pressão, neto 2 se suicida." << endl;
        kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);
    }
}
}

void
proc_filho1(int dtnasc) {
int num_segundos = 0;
int pid_filho = 0;

while (true) {
    sleep(1);
    num_segundos ++;
    cout << "Sou o processo filho 1 (PID " << getpid() << "), estou rodando há " << num_segundos << " segundos." << endl;
    if (num_segundos == 15 && ! (pid_filho = fork())) proc_neto1(dtnasc + num_segundos);
    if (dtnasc + num_segundos == 50) {
        cout << "Filho 1 ficou louco! Matou seu pai (PID = " << getppid() << ")" << endl;
        kill(getppid(), SIGKILL);
    }
    if (dtnasc + num_segundos == 55) {
        cout << "Filho 1 continua louco! Matou seu filho (PID " << pid_filho << ")" << endl;
        kill(pid_filho, SIGKILL);
    }
    if (dtnasc + num_segundos == 57) {
        cout << "Não aguentando a pressão, filho 1 se suicida." << endl;
        kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);
    }
}
}

void
proc_filho2(int dtnasc) {
int num_segundos = 0;

while (true) {
    sleep(1);
    num_segundos ++;
    cout << "Sou o processo filho 2 (PID " << getpid() << "), estou rodando há " << num_segundos << " segundos." << endl;
    if (num_segundos == 15 && ! fork()) proc_neto2(dtnasc + num_segundos);
}
}

int
main(int argc, char ** argv) {
int num_segundos = 0;
int pidPai = getpid();
system("pstree -s pidPai");

while (true) {
    sleep(1);
    num_segundos ++;
    //int pidPai = getpid();
    cout << "Sou o processo pai (PID " << pidPai << "), estou rodando há " << num_segundos << " segundos." << endl;

    // aos 10 segundos, gera o filho 1.
    if (num_segundos == 10 && ! fork()) proc_filho1(num_segundos);
    // aos 20 segundos, gera o filho 2.
    if (num_segundos == 20 && ! fork()) proc_filho2(num_segundos);
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que acontece é que você está literalmente executando o comando `pstree -s pidPai` enquanto que o certo seria substituir a palavra "pidPai" pelo número *PID* do processo atual. Segue a correção:

```
int pidPai = getpid();
system(string("pstree -s " + to_string(pidPai)).c_str());
```

Não se esqueça de incluir o *header* `string` no início do código.